# Is it possible to add an image to a cell Table in Ant Design Tables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, frontend, ant-design-pro

I am trying to create a column that in his entries will include a small picture and a name. 
How can I do so using Ant Design's table?

https://ant.design/components/table/
I can't seem to find anything related in the docs or the examples.

Answer (score 7):

There is a mistake in the accepted answer , here how you do it

```
{
      title: "Image",
      dataIndex: "ImageURL",  // this is the value that is parsed from the DB / server side
      render: theImageURL => <img alt={theImageURL} src={theImageURL} />  // 'theImageURL' is the variable you must declare in order the render the URL
}
```

You need to declare `theImageURL` and then use it with the `alt` and `src`.

Answer (score 5):

If you were using the table in a similar way as to the examples shown in their docs.(Using a datasource array)

You could do something like this

```
const columns = [
 {
    title: '',
    dataIndex: 'image_URL_here',
    render:  () => <img src={`image_URL_here`} />
 }
]
```

Comment: You have a mistake in your answer , please look below.

Answer (score 0):

```css
      {
          title: 'Image',
          dataIndex: 'avatar',
          width: 50,
          maxWidth: 50,
          render: (t, r) => <img src={`${r.avatar}`} />
        },
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer about what are you doing in that code block.